# Getting error as "ERROR: permission denied for schema public" while executing a sql script in Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and running postgres sql in a docker container running on port 5432 on a  VM powered by GCP.

First of all I entered  `sudo -u postgres psql` to enter into the database as postgres superuser.

After that executed the following commands as superuser

```
CREATE DATABASE retail_db;
CREATE USER retail_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'retail_password';
```

Also granted the permission to the user retail_user on the db retail_db

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE retail_db TO retail_user;
```

All of this things im doing in my home directory where there's a folder I have kept named retail_db which contains two SQL scripts one for table creation and one for data insertion into the table.
After that to create the tables used the script to enter into the db

```
psql -U retail_user -h localhost -p 5432 -d retail_db -W
```

And to create the tables used

```
\i retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql
```

Ideally it should create all the tables but im getting an error like

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:12: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE departments (
^

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:23: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE categories (
^

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:37: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE products (
^

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:54: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE customers (
^

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:66: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE orders (
^

psql:retail_db/create_db_tables_pg.sql:80: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE order_items (

I don't understand here I have given all the permission to the retail_user but its still throwing this error.

When i see the users table using `\du` command inside the db console i get something like

```
                                                       List of roles
       Role name       |                         Attributes                         |       Member of        | Description 
-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------
 demo_user             |                                                            | {}                     | 
 retail_user           |                                                            | {}                     | 
 sms1_user             |                                                            | {pg_read_server_files} | 
 postgres              | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}                     | 
 roster_user           |                                                            | {}                     | 
 sms_user              |                                                            | {}                     |
```

Is there anything im overdoing or missing?
Am fairly new to Psql so don't have much idea so apologies in advance.